# Gameplay video on android

Tags: screencast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible record in-game videos?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/is-it-possible-record-in-game-videos)

I don't know where exactly to ask this question:

How can i make gameplay video from android device ?
I need to capture video

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-capture-video-stream-from-android-phone-screen-and-show-it-on-laptop. I don't think you'll find a solution that gives you a decent framerate, unfortunately. It seems that Android makes it difficult to access the video buffer.

Comment: I just posted another answer to that that may get you up to a 30 FPS video.