# Android Software or Device to present Application on Screen

Tags: video, screen, screenshots

Well this is something that came to my mind, Does anyone know if there is a Device or a cable that i can plug to a DataShow so it is possible to present an Android Application live and fullscreen, doing all the tap and swipe events?

If not at least is there is something that its able to record a Screencast of an android application for presentation purpose  of course?

PD. BTW i did not found right tag for this question, so if someone can retag it it would be nice too :D

Comment: See [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-capture-video-stream-from-android-phone-screen-and-show-it-on-laptop) for screencasting live and [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/is-it-possible-record-in-game-videos) for recording the device screen using the device.  It's probably better to capture live and record at the PC I would think, to get a better framerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to found that the best way to do this is with a project call androidscreenscast, which is really easy and great:

- just plug your phone.
- Downloads the jnl on the [site](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/)
- And enjoy your screen

I wrote a post about my experience [Present your android application on a Datashow](http://www.necronet.info/2011/08/present-your-android-application-on.html).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to connect an Android phone via the 3.5 mm headphone jack (using TV out), with a [RCA cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector) if the project supports it, or some variation, of course.
Also, I think there are now tablets which have a HDMI output port (or some variation) which you can connect to a datashow (eventually with a VGA adapter).

When connected, what is projected is exactly what you see on your device.

Comment: can you point me out this 3.5 mm headphone jack solution looks interesting have you try it successfully yourself?

Comment: yes I did, it is very easy actually... look at this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iiwT06dg0HU

Comment: :O it display the video as an output... nice i think i'll stay with the software solution