# How do I stream my Android screen to my mac?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, streaming, screen-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I project the screen of my android phone for a presentation?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/how-do-i-project-the-screen-of-my-android-phone-for-a-presentation)

I want to live stream my Android phone while I'm playing a game. So far, my attempt is to stream my Android's screen to my mac, **then** from my mac, live stream it using [Procaster](http://new.livestream.com/broadcast-live/encoder).

So what do I need to accomplish this? **I don't have** a rooted phone. I just got it so I don't want to void my warranty at any time soon.

If my approach isn't the best way to do it, what can you suggest? I've already read ( [How do I project the screen of my Android phone for a presentation?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/how-do-i-project-the-screen-of-my-android-phone-for-a-presentation) ) but the solutions provided there are for rooted phones.

Comment: Root is generally required because Android doesn't make the raw screen buffer available to apps, as far as I understand.  The most-upvoted answer doesn't require root because it uses the SDK tools.  Unless your phone has DLNA (and you can receive/record it on your PC) I think that's about all there is.  Feel free to offer a bounty on the other question though.  See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12262/1465