# Screen recording tool for the samsung galaxy tab

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible record videos of my screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/is-it-possible-record-videos-of-my-screen)

IS there an available video screen recording tool for the samsung galaxy tab, or any other android device, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool called [Ashot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ashot/), but the device has to be connected to a PC and it has a pretty low framerate.

Comment: I tried it and didn't install correctly on my pc

Comment: I think it uses Java, so make sure you have a proper version of JRE installed. EDIT: instructions here: http://www.mightypocket.com/2010/09/installing-android-screenshots-screen-capture-screen-cast-for-windows/