# Movie or Video of mobile web application for demo

Tags: screencast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible record videos of my screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/is-it-possible-record-videos-of-my-screen)

Is there any way to capture mobile activities of user on mobile capture as a video.
I have samsung galaxy S running 2.3, is it possble using this? or is such feature introduced Android 3.0

or, if above is not possible, could you please help me out in finding out any software which does window activity capturing in Windows7 , I will use Android emulator to create video of my  mobile web application.

-Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Screencast Video Recorder FREE](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ms.screencastfree) and if it works you can get the paid version [Screencast Video Recorder](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ms.screencast).

For Windows I'm sure many software exists. Why don't you ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com) if you can't find one.