# Is there a screen capture app for Android which captures a video?

Tags: video-recording

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible record videos of my screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/is-it-possible-record-videos-of-my-screen)

Is there a screen capture app for Android which captures a video? I want to capture the video in realtime.I want to make an app which will run in the background and do the analysis of things that appear of phones screen .

Comment: Questions work better when they're about a problem trying to be solved rather than a pre-defined solution (an app) that you're trying to find. Don't use the site as a search service.

Comment: I posted this question originally on superuser , but it has been migrated . I have edited the question to make more sense here.

Answer (score 1):

Look [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms.screencast) (tegra 2/3 incompartible).
Also may be usable [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ashot) project for PC.

Comment: I'm using this app to record bugs I find for my work. It's great.

Answer (score 0):

for video capture I've not yet found anything (beyond the cheat of running the app in an emulator and using Camtasia or FRAPS to capture video of that)

for real-time analysis of what's happening in the video stack for some devices something like [PVRtune](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrtune.asp) is a great starting point